# Modify file without creating a copy

Tags: permissions, files, storage, editing

Is it technically possible to edit a file directly and don't create a copy inside the application directory ?

I want to annotate an image or a PDF directly but every application saves a copy instead of modify my file.

Comment: This is nothing to do with Android, but any way that's the norm in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing which would prevent apps from modifying data files in-place. If they don't do so, then it's because the app developer decided so.